# how to jump to the implementation of c++ functions built by myself?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile, cmake

this seems like a stupid question, but it has bothered me for a long time. First of all, I build the leveldb by myself, and `make install`. Then, I can use `#include <leveldb/db.h>` etc. But, I fail to `jump to the implementation` of some functions. ps: I'm using vscode and the vscode-cmake extension.

[image]

For example, I can not jump to implementation of `Open` funciton.

[image]

Comment: It might help to add debug symbols when building leveldb: `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` or `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo`.

Comment: Installing a library is not the same as telling your project to use a library.

Comment: @sweenish no, but `target_link_libraries()` does, and OP clearly has that,

Comment: The fact that you have `add_definitions(..., "-g")` indicates that you are not using cmake's normal Debug/Release mechanism (as reffered to by @Thomas). But if you are reffering to intellisense's code navigation, that may not be related. Is the CMakeLists.txt at the root of the workspace you are oppening in VSCode? Relative paths can get confused when that's not the case.

Comment: @Thomas @Frank I rebuild the leveldb with `Debug` mode, remove the `add_definitions(..., "-g")` and make the CMakeList.txt locate at the root. But it's not OK. Are there some wrong with VSCode? I decided to use IDE and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess, when installing leveldb you'll basically end up with the leveldb's headers and the library binary.

You should instead try to integrate leveldb source directly in your project using FetchContent module.

ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html